# Forum plugin with private forum option

Tags: forum

I'm in need of a forum plugin for Wordpress that has an option for a private forum that is only accessible (both for reading and posting) to registered users.  Restricted posting appears to be *de rigueur*, but restricted viewing appears to be harder to find.

Ideally, it'll integrate directly with Wordpress but if it needs to open in a separate window (*a la* BBPress) then that's fine.

I've been looking around at different Wordpress forum options (such as BBPress and Mingle), but I can't see whether any support this feature.

Does anyone know of a simple forum solution that offers this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Simple:Press](http://simple-press.com/)

Can limit forums to no access, read only, limited, standard, full, moderator

It's decently simple, I've been using it a bit for my personal blog.
I didn't have too hard of a time integrating it.
Lots of features available, with pretty fine grained ability to turn things on and off

Also, as information, bbPress no longer requires stand-alone operation
It is now [developed as a plugin](http://bbpress.org/blog/2011/06/bbpress-2-0-beta-3/) and is maturing rapidly.
I've integrated it into one of my sites with no problems. However, I don't think it meets your needs. Just wanted to include the info in case you were interested.

Comment: Thanks mate, good answer - I've actually gone with Vanilla which has Wordpress integration by way of an iframe.  It seems good so far but if anything goes wrong I'll jump ship to Simple:Press.

Comment: Sure, the support forums at simple press have been great to me. I had 2 plugin conflicts over the past couple years we were able to work through. Simple press actually has a tonne of features, I went with bbPress beta plugin for my new site, as I need absoltely no features. They are both excellent depending on just what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Mingle Forums is capable of this - http://minglecommunities.com/mingle-forum-install-guide/